# How Row into dynamic number of columns MySQL with saldo?

Tags: mysql, row

I need select wich show rows to clumn to dynamic..
I have 4 table

```
1)sizes  (1,40 2,50 3,60)
2)goods  (id,parentId,model)
3)property_goods(id,id_size,id_goods) 
4)moves  (with action income,outcome,return,moving,selling)..
```

First time I enter category goods and name goods with unique model
Second time I entered for this goods property like size 40 50 60 etc
After than I shuold show select from goods,sizes,property,moves
like This but enter code herethis first time not action in moves table

```
  Name    Model    40   50    60   
  Nike     GTGT     0    0    0
```

Third time I do it income for warehouse

```
   moves
id  model  id_sizes qty
1    GTGT    1      1 
2    GTGT    2      2 
2    GTGT    3      3
```

After refresh I should take frome moves

```
  Name    Model    40   50    60   
  Nike     GTGT     1    2    3
```

Helpme how build select

[sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bd18](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bd18)

:)
На русском
Нужно из четерех таблиц вывести в таком виде..
Имеется 4 таблиц
1)sizes размеры (1,40 2,50 3,60)
2)goods товары (id,parentId,model) деревовидный
3)property_goods характеристики (id,id_size,id_goods) одного товара несколько размеры
4)moves (с типом приход,реализация,возврат,перемещение).. движение
Сначало заполняем справочник размеров 1,40 2,50,3,60
Пример ввода товый товар с характеристками
после этого в селекте должен показать в таком виде

```
наименование модель размеры динамический тоесть 40 50 60
```

смотря какой размеры есть в характеристике. селект должен брать из четерых таблиц если товар новый в справочнике у него не было никакой движение все равно показать с остатками 0 left join moves ..

Comment: Your sql fiddle is wrong

Comment: I still can't understand, what result you need- could you explain by words a little more?

Comment: ok First When user open programm interface user see only one category goods..All goods category some like treeview left side. And user add new goods for table goods after posting I should show name goods and dynamicly size and balance.

Comment: Its hard to understand you :) Try to explain in russian pls ;) Может тогда получится понять)

Answer (score 0):

There is online demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bd18/7

```
select g.name, g.model,
max(p.id_sizes = 11) as 'Size 40',
max(p.id_sizes = 4) as 'Size 41',
max(p.id_sizes = 5) as 'Size 43',
max(p.id_sizes = 6) as 'Size 44',
max(p.id_sizes = 1) as 'Size 8',
max(p.id_sizes = 2) as 'Size 9',
max(p.id_sizes = 8) as 'Size XL',
max(p.id_sizes = 9) as 'Size XL-50',
max(p.id_sizes = 7) as 'Size XXL',
max(p.id_sizes = 10) as 'Size XXX'
from goods g
left join property p on p.id_goods = g.id
group by g.id
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: 10x But I don't how fill sizes table user.I need dynamicly It is necessary to include a table moves with look action field income or outcome. Summ income-outcome=saldo..

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand you and help if it's so